# Login Servlet not redirecting to other JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am working on the java web application which is working absolutely fine on other systems but after configuring it on the new system my login page is not forwarding the request to the home page,After login it tries to load the page and gets back to the login page. I can't understand the reason, their are no errors.

My login.jsp looks like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://devel.payo.org/tlibs/payo-core" prefix="payo" %>

<html:html>

<c:choose><c:when test="${not empty loggedUser}">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=${pathPrefix}/home">
    </head>
</c:when><c:otherwise>

    <jsp:include page="/pages/general/layout/head.jsp" />
    <payo:customizedFilePath type="style" name="login.css" var="loginUrl" groupId="${empty loggedUserId ? cookie.groupId.value : ''}" groupFilterId="${empty loggedUserId ? cookie.groupFilterId.value : ''}" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="${loginUrl}" />">    

    <jsp:include flush="true" page="/pages/access/includes/loginDefinitions.jsp" /> 

    <payo:includeCustomizedFile type="static" name="login.jsp" groupId="${empty loggedUserId ? cookie.groupId.value : ''}" groupFilterId="${empty loggedUserId ? cookie.groupFilterId.value : ''}" />   

    <script>
        if (!is.ie6) {
            var td = $('loginRegistration');
            var div = $('loginRegistrationDiv');
            if (td && div) {
                div.style.height = (td.getHeight() - 10) + "px";
            }
        }
        ensureLoginForm();
    </script>

</c:otherwise></c:choose>

</html:html>
```

The same application is working fine on all the other systems.
I am using apache tomcat 7 with sql server 2012.
I would be grateful If someone can help me in this regards as I have already wasted two days in understanding the problem.

Comment: we would like to know what is different between your systems? Have you changed the directory structure?

Comment: @TechBreak system is almost the same ,its also core i7 with intel processor, but its the new one so I had to configure everything from the scratch, this system came with windows 10 the previous one was also with windows 10.. Only the differences are related to hardware configurations, nothing else.